# informative examples for understanding spectral triples

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I am at the beginning of my thesis work and I am trying to understand spectral triples.  I can recall the definition but I have no informative examples with which to make sense of it.  What are some examples I can keep in mind to help me put this definition in context?

Comment: How comfortable are you with the commutative case?

Comment: I am fairly new to the subject.  Would the commutative case be spectral triples associated with C*-algebras that are algebras of continuous complex-valued functions on a compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: Yes - this was the starting point for Connes's definitions! I don't know where you are reading about spectral triples, but if they don't give some discussion of the case $C^\infty(M)$ then you need to find a source which does. A few minutes of Googling turns up e.g. this Master's thesis http://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/Richard.pdf

Comment: The setting in which I have seen spectral triples are in papers by Christiansen, Ivan, and Lapidus to obtain results on function spaces on fractals.